# lambda calculus reduction: (((lambda f (lambda x (f x))) (lambda y (* y y))) 12)

Tags: lambda-calculus

given the input

> `(((lambda f (lambda x (f x))) (lambda y (* y y))) 12)`

**`what does this step evaluate to: lambda x (f x)`**

I am trying to evaluate this and I have the following tree so far:

[image]

how do I evaluate this ? looking for guidance on what I might be doing wrong or how to proceed with this.

Comment: The tree is inconsistent. There are no "apply" nodes under "lambda" nodes. However, f is applied on x and (*) is applied on y and the result is again applied on y.

Comment: The tree written is correct.  Apply is just implicit in lambda calculus, indicated by concatenation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lambda expressions are evaluated by reducing the leftmost redex first.  A redex is something of the form $(\lambda a.b)c$ .  Your expression is $(\lambda f.\lambda x.fx)(\lambda y . *yy)~12$.  So your first redex is

$$(\lambda f.\lambda x.fx)(\lambda y . *yy)$$

So you substitute $(\lambda y . *yy)$ for $y$ in $\lambda x.fx$ to get $$\lambda x.(\lambda y . *yy)x~ 12$$

Then your next redex is the entire expression, ($(\lambda y . *yy)x$ is also a redex but it isn't the leftmost one) substituting $12$ in for $x$.  So you get $$(\lambda y . *yy)~12$$

Then your last redex is the entire expression again so you get

$$*~12~12$$

Comment: the leftmost redex concept is a little hard for me. What if the redex thats we are substituting is more complex that the one in this case, can we simplify it before substituting ? For E.g. (lambda y (lambda g (g (* y y))))

Comment: @Dhruv The expression you wrote there isn't a redex, I'll assume you mean it as the $c$ for some $(\lambda a.b)c$ .  And the answer is...sometimes.  Evaluating left to right gives you the property that if the lambda expression has a redex-free final form, then you will reach it.  If you evaluate in arbitrary order, you could loop forever.

Comment: I posted another question to https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/122115/lambda-calculus-beta-reductions-lambda-f-lambda-x-f-x-f-lambda-y-l  as a follow up.