# lambda calculus beta reductions: ((((lambda f (lambda x ((f x) f))) (lambda y (lambda g (g (* y y))))) 2) (lambda a a))

Tags: lambda-calculus, functional-programming

My question is in continuation to [lambda calculus reduction: (((lambda f (lambda x (f x))) (lambda y (* y y))) 12)](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/122084/110052)

given the input:

```
((((lambda f (lambda x ((f x) f))) (lambda y (lambda g (g (* y y))))) 2) (lambda a a))
```

I want to understand the order of reductions that I should take. in the above mentioned question it was suggested to me to apply left most reduction.

I want to check if this is a valid 1st step towards leftmost reduction:

[image]

Or should f= λy.λg.g(*y y) instead ?
What it might boil down to is: am I allowed to solve the sub-trees up before applying the solution from the right subtree on the left sub-tree?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
(\lambda f. \lambda x .f x f)
(\lambda y.\lambda g. g (* y y))
2
(\lambda a. a)
$$

The leftmost redex $(\lambda a.b)c$ is

$$(\lambda f. \lambda x .f x f)(\lambda y.\lambda g. g (* y y))$$

with

- $a = f$
- $b = \lambda x .f x f$
- $c = (\lambda y.\lambda g. g (* y y))$

Don't forget to make sure that $x$ doesn't exist in $c$, because if so then doing an immediate beta reduction would change the meaning of the expression.  So the redex reduces to:

$$(\lambda x .(\lambda y.\lambda g. g (* y y)) x (\lambda y.\lambda g. g (* y y)))$$

Overall giving

$$
(\lambda x . (\lambda y.\lambda g. g (* y y)) x (\lambda y.\lambda g. g (* y y)))
2
(\lambda a. a)
$$

The next redex is $(\lambda y. \cdots)x$